Neovim netrw file explorer is not seeing my C# associated directories or files. Any ideas what could be causing this?
I am trying to get into C# programming, as it is what a friend programs in. I am trying to set it up in Neovim, but any C# files or directories that contain them do not show up in netrw directory listing.
WindowsFileExplorer
NeovimNetrw
I manually created .cs files in neovim and edited them. Neovim can't see them, and gives a shell 255 error while trying to run the :make r command. I have the Mason and Treesitter set up. I am unsure if the compiling and directory problems are related. May have something to do with dotnet?
I used dotnet new console, and those files also did not show, even in a new directory.
